# Hint: vector space $V=\{f:S\rightarrow F\}$ is a finite dimensional vector space over F if and only if $S$ is finite.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

No answers, please! Just a hint.

Let $S$ be a set and let $F$ be a field. Prove that the vector space $V=\{f:S\rightarrow F\}$ of all maps from $S$ to $F$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$ if and only if $S$ is finite.

EDIT: Thank you all for the hints. This is my proof. How is it?

Suppose $S$ is finite. Let's define $\delta_s$ as follows:
$$\delta_s(x)=\begin{cases}
1&x=s\\
0&x\neq s
\end{cases}$$
We can express any function $f$ in terms of $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$: $f = \sum_{s \in S} a_i \delta_s$, so $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$ is a finite spanning set. Thus, $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. Conversely, suppose to the contrary that $S$ is infinite. Then  $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$ is an infinite spanning set. However, this contradicts the fact that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, and so $S$ must be finite.

Comment: For a hint:  well, surely you can show that $V$ is finite dimensional when $S$ is finite, no?  Try to write out an explicit basis for $V$ in that case.  That construction will also show you that $V$ is infinite dimensional when $S$ is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: think about the functions $(\delta_s:s\in S)$ defined by $\delta_s(x)=1$ if $x=s$ and $\delta_s(x)=0$ if $x\ne s$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it? Suppose $S$ is finite. Let's define $\delta_s$ as follows:
$$\delta_s(x)=\begin{cases}
1&x=s\\
0&x\neq s
\end{cases}$$
We can express any function $f$ in terms of $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$: $f = \sum_{s \in S} a_i \delta_s$, so $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$ is a finite spanning set. Thus, $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space. [And then prove the other way]

Comment: Conversely, suppose to the contrary that $S$ is infinite. Then  $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$ is an infinite spanning set. However, this contradicts the fact that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, and so $S$ must be finite.

Comment: Your second comment is not quite right. Every nonzero vector space over an infinite field (like $\Bbb{R}$) has an infinite spanning set. You should show that there is an infinite set of linearly independent elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Define $f+g$ and $af$ for $a\in F$ and $f,g\in V$.

Find a basis of $V$.

Comment: How's this? Suppose $S$ is finite. Let's define $\delta_s$ as follows:
$$\delta_s(x)=\begin{cases}
1&x=s\\
0&x\neq s
\end{cases}$$
We can express any function $f$ in terms of $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$: $f = \sum_{s \in S} a_i \delta_s$, so $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$ is a finite spanning set. Thus, $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Conversely, suppose to the contrary that $S$ is infinite. Then  $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$ is an infinite spanning set. Moreover, suppose $f = \sum_{a\in A}c_ae_a = 0$. We want to show that $c_a=0$ for all $a \in A$. For an arbitrary $a' \in A$, we know that $(\sum c_ae_a)(a') = 0$ and that $$(\sum c_ae_a)(a') = \sum c_ae_a(a') = 0 \longrightarrow c_{a'} = 0$$ for any $a' \in A$. Thus, $\{\delta_s \mid s \in S\}$ is linearly independent. However, this contradicts the fact that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, and so $S$ must be finite.